# Calculate angles between two other angles

Tags: c++, mathematics, lighting

I am trying to implement a FOV for my light casting algorithm. In the diagram below each white line represents a ray cast from a `std::vector<float>` of normalized radians. How can I only include angles which lie between the two green lines? (The FOV min and max).

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how do you filter the vector of ints to be between the two radians values of the fov?

Comment: Yes. Or filter before they are even placed into the vector.

Comment: What units are the radians in? They are not floats so what are they? What do you mean normalized radians if they are ints

Comment: Sorry. Yes, they are floats. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: Is there a way of making the first green line 0 then seeing if the angle of the other lines aren't greater than the second green line?

Comment: I guess your problem  is to find the objects that have angle segments that intersects with your view angle segment.  In a second time you might want to optimize  and not draw hidden objects => considering the distances
...

Comment: I've already calculated the intersections and it work perfectly for a 360 degree casting, however I wish to limit the projection to the FOV so the angles vector should include only the fov min, the fov max and all the angles that are between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www.xarg.org/2010/06/is-an-angle-between-two-other-angles/) which works pretty well.

```
bool angleBetween(float _angle, float _min, float _max)
{
    float angle = std::fmod(360 + (rad2deg(_angle)), 360);
    float min = std::fmod(3600000 + rad2deg(_min), 360);
    float max = std::fmod(3600000 + rad2deg(_max), 360);

    if(min < max)
        return (min <= angle && angle <= max);

    return (min <= angle || angle <= max);
}
```

Comment: It seems like it would be simpler to compare the radian values instead of converting to degrees first.